# what does this remote javascript do that is attached to my email? "http://rum-static.pingdom.net/prum.min.js"

Tags: javascript, security, gmail

"http://rum-static.pingdom.net/prum.min.js"

!function(){"use strict";function t(t,e){return Object.keys(t).map(function(n){return n+"="+(e?t[n]:encodeURIComponent(t[n]))}).join("&")}function e(t,e){var n,o,r={};return t&&"string"==typeof t?(t.trim().split("&").forEach(function(t){n=t.indexOf("="),o=t.substring(n+1),r[t.substr(0,n)]=e?o:decodeURIComponent(o)}),r):r}function n(t){return t instanceof Date&&(t=t.valueOf()),"number"==typeof t&&parseInt(t.toString().substring(0,10),10)}function o(){var t={},e=arguments;e[0]instanceof Array&&(e=e[0]);for(var n=0,a=e.length;n-1}).join("").replace(o.storageKey+"=",""))},_objectToCookie:function(e){n.document.cookie=r(t(e))}};return a}function c(n,o){function r(t){if(c&&t){var n=e(c.getItem(o.storageKey));return n?n[t]:""}return""}function i(n,r){if(c&&n)try{var i=c.getItem(o.storageKey),a=i?e(i):{};a[n]=r,c.setItem(o.storageKey,t(a))}catch(t){console.error("unable to store "+n+" in storage.",t)}}function a(t){c&&t&&c.removeItem(t)}var c;return function(){var t=o.storageKey+"_enabled";if(n.localStorage&&"1"===n.localStorage.getItem(t))return void(c=n.localStorage);if(n.localStorage)try{if(n.localStorage.setItem(t,1),"1"===n.localStorage.getItem(t))return void(c=n.localStorage)}catch(t){console.error("localStorage.setItem() failed. Using cookies")}c=s(n,o)}(),{get:r,set:i,remove:a}}function u(t,e,o){var s={modules:[],send:void 0,storage:void 0,storageKey:t.storageKey,id:t.id,url:t.url,ver:t.ver,sessionIDLength:t.sessionIDLength,sessionLifetime:t.sessionLifetime,retVisitor:t.retVisitor,getSessionInfo:function(){var t=s.storage.get("sid"),e=parseInt(s.storage.get("sst"),10),o=n(Date.now());return t&&e?o-e>s.sessionLifetime?s.sessionStart(o-e0?a(u.secureConnectionStart):-1}function a(t){return t>0?t-u.navigationStart:-1}function s(t){return{nS:0,cS:a(t.connectStart),cE:a(t.connectEnd),dLE:a(t.domainLookupEnd),dLS:a(t.domainLookupStart),fS:a(t.fetchStart),hS:i(),rE:a(t.redirectEnd),rS:a(t.redirectStart),reS:a(t.requestStart),resS:a(t.responseStart),resE:a(t.responseEnd),uEE:a(t.unloadEventEnd),uES:a(t.unloadEventStart),dL:a(t.domLoading),dI:a(t.domInteractive),dCLES:a(t.domContentLoadedEventStart),dCLEE:a(t.domContentLoadedEventEnd),dC:a(t.domComplete),lES:a(t.loadEventStart),lEE:a(t.loadEventEnd)}}var c,u,g=t.performance||{};!function(){if(u=g.timing){var e={};c=setTimeout(function(){if(e=f(u,e),e.loadEventEnd){clearInterval(c);var o=[];o.push(d(t)),o.push(r()),o.push(s(e)),n(o)}},25)}}()}!function(t){var e=[g];u({storageKey:"pa-l",id:"",url:"//rum-collector-2.pingdom.net/img/beacon.gif",ver:"1.4.0",sessionIDLength:parseInt("8",10),sessionLifetime:parseInt("1800",10),retVisitor:24*parseInt("30",10)*3600},t,e)}(window)}();

Comment: try this. http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1):

Pingdom is a uptime and performance monitoring service that has monitoring probe servers all over the world.

Real User Monitoring (RUM) gives you insight into performance and helps you answer questions like, how does your website really perform from a specific country or web browser.

Just visit https://www.pingdom.com/product/performance-monitoring/ for more details from official website.